# Not able to access content of sharepoint folders using shareplum [Python]

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, python

I've asked this question on stackoverflow too, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135800/not-able-to-access-content-of-sharepoint-folders-using-shareplum). But someone told me I'd have better luck on sharepoint stackexchange.

I'm trying to download a few csv files that reside in a document thats part of a sharepoint list. Sharepoint is not on-premise therefore requires O365 Auth.

My code till now:

```
in[1]: from shareplum import Site
       from shareplum import Office365

       authcookie = Office365('https://my.sharepoint.com', 
       username='username', password='password').GetCookies()
       site = Site('https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/documentLibrary/', 
       authcookie=authcookie)

       sp_list = site.List('listName')
       sp_list.GetListItems('All Documents')

out[1]: [{'Name': 'Folder1',
          'Modified': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 12, 7, 24),
          'Modified By': 'Jane Doe'},
        {'Name': 'Folder2',
         'Modified': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 16, 2, 41),
         'Modified By': 'Dane Joe'}]
```

So I'm able to get folder information about the files present in list by using `GetListItems('All Documents')`.

Folders 1 and 2 are a part of the list. ***The csv files I want to downloads are in folder 1. I am not able to find a way to list any files from folder 1 and download them.***

I've already tried the following:

```
in[2]: sp_list.GetListItems('Folder 1')
out[2]: KeyError: 'Folder 1'
```

The [documentation](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) isn't very clear, I do not get what the following does or is used for:

```
sp_data = new_list.GetListItems(fields=['ID', 'Title'])
```

Comment: I think Shareplum does not provide any API where you can download the actual file, instead it just provide the metadata information.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a try below [API](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html#folders) to download files in the specified folder:

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/This Folder')
```

To [download files](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html#id1):

```
folder.get_file('source.csv')
```

Test demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/downloadfile.py

BR